# Do LED lights work well for CAT III B operations?

Tags: ils, airport-lighting

Does any airport equipped with LED lights for all the CATIII B Components? If so, is there any history that it caused difficulty in aircraft operations?

We are planning to install our new runway with CAT III B lighting with LED fitments.

Comment: You have a lot of questions, you might condense this down into a single question.

Comment: Can you make this question more about one thing? Just because you are asking about CAT III B lights, doesn't mean all questions related to that can be added together in a single one.

Comment: Will do that, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can do Cat IIIB with a HUD (I'd have said that you're limited to Cat IIIA with one, but somebody may have a capability I'm not aware of) but no, LED lights generally don't wash out a HUD any worse than other lights do.  If your HUD brightness is sufficiently dim, then bright enough lights of any sort can wash it out, but that just requires you to turn the brightness up a bit.

I've never heard of or seen any "Sea of Blue" effect from LED lights, and I don't think LED lights have particularly worse glare (or any other) characteristics when used as runway lighting.  They're somewhat distinctive, but not particularly worse.

If LED lights have regulatory approval for what you want to do, I'd say that right there is the answer to your questions.  And if they don't, well, then that's also an answer.